# Why does terraform sporadically fail to create this api gateway resource?

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway

I have a terraform module that creates an API gateway instance, and connects several lambdas to it. It builds and reliably creates the API, but often has a failure in the build that needs to be solved by a simple repeat of the terraform apply command, sometimes twice.

This is the relevant part of the module:

```
locals {
  lambda_endpoints_by_path = { for e in var.lambda_endpoints : e.api_path => e }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "gateway_resource" {
  for_each    = local.lambda_endpoints_by_path
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.root_resource_id
  path_part   = each.value.api_path
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "gateway_method" {
  for_each             = local.lambda_endpoints_by_path
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.gateway_resource[each.key].id
  http_method          = each.value.method
  authorization        = "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
  authorizer_id        = aws_api_gateway_authorizer.authorizer.id
  authorization_scopes = each.value.scopes
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "gateway_response_200" {
  for_each    = local.lambda_endpoints_by_path
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.gateway_resource[each.key].id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.gateway_method[each.key].http_method
  status_code = "200"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "integration_response" {
  for_each    = local.lambda_endpoints_by_path
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.gateway_resource[each.key].id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.gateway_method[each.key].http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.gateway_response_200[each.key].status_code
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "proxy_integration" {
  for_each                = local.lambda_endpoints_by_path
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.gateway_resource[each.key].id
  http_method             = each.value.method
  integration_http_method = each.value.method
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${each.value.lambda_arn}:$${stageVariables.env}/invocations"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
}
```

`var.lambda_endpoints` is a list of objects with relevant information about each lambda endpoint.

When it fails, this is the error:

```
Error: Error creating API Gateway Integration: NotFoundException: Invalid Method identifier specified
Error: Error creating API Gateway Integration Response: NotFoundException: Invalid Integration identifier specified
```

When it fails, the first rerun clears the error creating the integration, and the second clears the error creating the integration response. Is there a reason that terraform isn't figuring out the build order on the first pass? How can I avoid these rebuild steps?

Comment: Possibly a bug, are you using the latest version of Terraform and the provider? If not you should upgrade, if it still fails, raise a bug in GitHub. IME bugs like this are pretty common in Terraform

Comment: This is on terraform 0.13.5 and the AWS provider 3.29.0. I'll see if bumping the provider does anything.

Comment: It's probably a bug but you won't get anyone to look at it unless you can re-create on the latest version of everything. Terraform is no on v 1.0.x so you'll need to update that too

Comment: Terraform can only judge if a resource has been created, based on the return value of the AWS API. I have seen cases where Terraform believes a resource has been created and is ready, when in fact AWS is still completing some initialisation. In those cases, rerunning the plan works without issue. I have sometimes had success by adding `depends_on` statements on some resources to try force the structure of the plan, but YMMV if this the source of the issues you are seeing.

Comment: My hunch is that it's a typical eventual-consistency problem with AWS, not Terraform.